# firebase messages deliver to ios from postman but not from server

Tags: ios, firebase, react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging, react-native-firebase

We are using React Native to build a react app. We want to move to data-only notifications to have more control over the notifications (using notifee library).

I am able to send a test notification with `data` object via firebase HTTP protocol using taskman, and the notification is delivered. No problems. It works for both physical and emulated android and physical iOS devices.

When we use our systems to trigger a notification/message to be sent, the notification is delivered to android, but `onMessage` or `setBackgroundMessageHandler` from firebase never fire on iOS.

#### BG message listener in `index.js` on RN app

```
import React from 'react';
import { AppRegistry } from 'react-native';
import messaging from '@react-native-firebase/messaging';
import App from './App';
import { name as appName } from './app.json';
import Providers from './src/Providers';

messaging().setBackgroundMessageHandler(async (remoteMessage) => {
  // logs for android, does not reach this line on ios
  console.log('remoteMessage in BG handler', remoteMessage);
  
  // ...do things with delivered data-only message
});

const AppRedux = () => (
  <Providers store={store}>
    <App />
  </Providers>
);

AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => AppRedux);

export default AppRedux;
```

#### Foreground listener in `useNotifications.tsx`

```
import { useEffect } from 'react';;
import messaging from '@react-native-firebase/messaging';
import { useNotificationPermission } from './useNotificationPermission';

export const usePushNotifications = () => {
  useNotificationPermission();
  
  const handleIncoming = async (remoteMessage: RemoteMessage) => {
    if (!remoteMessage) {
      // EVEN THIS does not fire on ios
      console.error('No remote message received');
      return;
    }

    // fires on android, does not on ios
    console.log('=== INCOMING ===', remoteMessage);
    
    // ...do something with message
  };


  useEffect(() => {
    // handle when app is open in foreground
    messaging().onMessage(handleIncoming);
  }, []);
};
```

#### Message payload from server

```
{
  "apns": {
    "payload": {
      "aps": {
        "content-available": 1
      }
    }
  },
  "data": {
    "notifee": {
      "data": {
        // OUR DATA
      },
      "title": "Hello",
      "body": "World citizens"
    }
  },
}
```

#### Assumptions

- I assume the backend is sending the task correctly, as it delivers to android just fine.
- I assume it is making it through the firebase system, as it is being passed on to the android device correctly.
- I assume the hangup could be either in APNS or on the device itself.

#### Questions

1. Is there an error in my code?
2. Is there an error in the message being sent?
3. Is there a way to view APNS logs and see whether the notification is being held up in APNS for some reason?

#### **What did you try and what were you expecting?**

I have tried stringifying various items inside "data" object (per firebase spec), did not work. I have tried adding `content-available: true` to our backend payload at the top level (not wrapped in APNS config dictionary) and that did not work. I have tried attaching APNS headers and that has not worked.

I expect "silent" data-only notifications to be delivered to ios devices.